# SQL: When and why are two on conditions allowed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, postgresql, join

Question:

I recently had an interesting SQL problem.
I had to get the leasing contract for a leasing object.

The problem was, there could be multiple leasing contracts per room, and multiple leasing object per room.

However, because of bad db tinkering, leasing contracts are assigned to the room, not the leasing object. So I had to take the contract number, and compare it to the leasing object number, in order to get the right results.

I thought this would do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_Room 

LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Room_LeasingObject 
    ON MAP_RMLOBJ_RM_UID = T_Room.RM_UID 

LEFT JON T_LeasingObject
    ON LOBJ_UID = MAP_RMLOBJ_LOBJ_UID

LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract  
    ON T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract.MAP_RMCTR_RM_UID = T_Room.RM_UID 

LEFT JOIN T_Contracts 
    ON T_Contracts.CTR_UID = T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract.MAP_RMCTR_CTR_UID 
    AND T_Contracts.CTR_No LIKE ( ISNULL(T_LeasingObject.LOBJ_No, '') + '.%'     ) 

WHERE ...
```

However, because the mapping table gets joined before I have the contract number, and I cannot get the contract number without having the mapping table, i have doubled entries.

The problem is a little more complicated, as rooms having no leasing contract needed also to show up, so I couldn't just use an inner join.

With a little bit experimenting, I found that this works as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_Room 

LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Room_LeasingObject 
    ON MAP_RMLOBJ_RM_UID = T_Room.RM_UID 

LEFT JON T_LeasingObject
    ON LOBJ_UID = MAP_RMLOBJ_LOBJ_UID

LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract  

LEFT JOIN T_Contracts 
    ON T_Contracts.CTR_UID = T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract.MAP_RMCTR_CTR_UID 
    ON T_MAP_Room_LeasingContract.MAP_RMCTR_RM_UID = T_Room.RM_UID 
    AND T_Contracts.CTR_No LIKE ( ISNULL(T_LeasingObject.LOBJ_No, '') + '.%'     ) 

WHERE ...
```

I now see why the two on conditions in one join, which usually are courtesy of query designer, can be useful, and what difference it makes.

I was wondering whether this is a MS-SQL/T-SQL specific thing, or whether this is standard sql.

So I tried in PostgreSQL with another 3 tables.

So I wrote this query on 3 other tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_dms_navigation

LEFT JOIN t_dms_document 
    ON NAV_DOC_UID = DOC_UID 

 LEFT JOIN t_dms_project 
    ON PJ_UID = NAV_PJ_UID
```

and tried to turn it into one with two on conditions

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_dms_navigation

LEFT JOIN t_dms_document 

 LEFT JOIN t_dms_project 
    ON PJ_UID = NAV_PJ_UID 
    ON NAV_DOC_UID = DOC_UID
```

So I thought it's t-sql specific, but quickly tried in MS-SQL too, just to find to my surprise that it doesn't work there either.

I thought it might be because of missing foreign keys, so i removed them on all tables in my room query, but it still did not work.

So here my question:
Why are 2 on conditions even legal, does this have a name, and why does it not work on my second example ?

Comment: "doesn't work" - do you get error messages? Those can be quite informative.

Comment: Error message: Invalid object name 't_dms_document'. But the name is correct (right db catalog also), if I do select * from t_dms_document i get results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's standard SQL. Each `JOIN` has to have a corresponding `ON` clause. All you're doing is shifting around the order that the joins happen in<sup>1</sup> - it's a bit like changing the bracketing of an expression to get around precedence rules.

```
A JOIN B ON <cond1> JOIN C ON <cond2>
```

First joins `A` and `B` based on `cond1`. It then takes that combined rowset and joins it to `C` based on `cond2`.

```
A JOIN B JOIN C ON <cond1> ON <cond2>
```

First joins `B` and `C` based on `cond1`. It then takes `A` and joins it to the previous combined rowset, based on `cond2`.

---

It should work in PostgreSQL - here's the relevant part of the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html) of the SELECT statement:

> where *from_item* can be one of:
>      [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ]
>       ( select ) [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ]
>       with_query_name [ [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ]
>       function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] | column_definition [, ...] ) ]
>       function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) AS ( column_definition [, ...] )
>       from_item [ NATURAL ] join_type from_item [ ON join_condition | USING ( join_column [, ...] ) ]

It's that last line that's relevant. Notice that it's a recursive definition - what can be to the left and right of a join can be anything - including more joins.

---

<sup>1</sup>As always with SQL, this is the *logical* processing order - the system is free to perform physical processing in whatever sequence it feels will work best, provided the result is consistent.

Comment: Ah, I C. And what I have in my second example is no join condition for table (b and c), only between (a and b) and (a and c), which can't work, hence the error, which is correct.